Why does gmock capture only work reliably with an added Invoke in DoAll of an ON_CALL
In very short: the issue I face is that in an
ON_CALL(...).WillByDefault(DoAll(..some capture..,Invoke([&captureValues]{..trace them...})));

the capture only works reliably if that "Invoke" is there. If I remove it, sometimes either the values are not captured correctly or they are not correctly passed on to the next expectation.
In detail: the productive code does the following:
HRESULT SomeClass::SomeMethod()
{
  HRESULT hr;
  int val1 = 4;
  int val2 = 7;
  hr = mockableObject.DoCall(val1, val2, &someOutObject);
  int someOutValue = 0;
  hr = someOutObject.DoOtherCall(&someOutValue);
  ...
  return hr;
}

DoCall returns an object, on that object DoOtherCall is called. val1 and val2 of DoCall shall be captured and used in the expactation of DoOtherCall to produce the returned result.
The combination of DoCall and DoOtherCall on the returned object by DoCall is executed several times in SomeClass::SomeMethod (just if you wonder why the setup is like it is, it's the only way I found how to put these alternating calls under expectations).
The test looks as follows:
TEST_F(MySomeClassTest,
       MAKE_TEST_NAME(precondition_or_setup,
         tested_action,
         expected_result))
{
  // Arrange
  SetupTestCase();

  // Act
  SomeClass uut;
  HRESULT hr = uut.SomeMethod();

  // Assert
  EXPECT_EQ(hr, S_OK);
}

The setup for the test is the following:
void MySomeClassTest::SetupTestCase()
{
  uint16 capturedVal1 = 0;
  uint16 capturedVal2 = 0;

  ON_CALL(mockedObject, DoCall(_, _, _))
    .WillByDefault(
      DoAll(
        SaveArg<0>(&capturedVal1), // Capture value 1
        SaveArg<1>(&capturedVal2), // Capture value 2
        Invoke([&capturedVal1, &capturedVal2]{std::cout << "Values 1, 2: " << capturedVal1 << ", " << capturedVal2 << std::endl;}),
        SetArgPointee<2>(&someOtherMock),
        Return(S_OK)));

  EXPECT_CALL(someOtherMock, DoOtherCall(_))
    .WillRepeatedly(
      Invoke([&capturedVal1, &capturedVal2](int* returnValue) {
          std::cout << "Values 1, 2: " << capturedVal1 << ", " << capturedVal2 << std::endl;
          *returnValue = capturedVal1 * capturedVal2;
          return S_OK;
      }));
}

With the Invoke line in the ON_CALL the tests run green.
If I remove the Invoke line (which basically I introduced just for being able to set a breakpoint and have a trace-output), not all captured values are correct in the EXPECT_CALL (there I trace the captured values as well).
More specifically: I know for sure DoCall's first two arguments are always > 0. But sometimes the second argument is 0 in the EXPECT_CALL's Invoke.
Anybody else faced this issue? Is it a gmock bug? Do I do something wrong?

Please provide [mcve]. Here you can show problem online.

Also you are doing something wrong. This calling of SetupTestCase(); indicates  you are not familiar with gtest API and general patterns how to write tests with gtest. This might be part of your problem.

Thanks for the link, I'll try to reproduce there. It is the minimum code possible to understand the environment, I don't see to reduce further. It's maybe even reduced too much as it's no more visible why I use the SetupTestCase().

Your test code has undefined behavior. Here:
void MySomeClassTest::SetupTestCase()
{
  uint16 capturedVal1 = 0;
  uint16 capturedVal2 = 0;

  ON_CALL(mockedObject, DoCall(_, _, _))
    .WillByDefault(
      DoAll(
        SaveArg<0>(&capturedVal1), // Capture value 1
        SaveArg<1>(&capturedVal2), // Capture value 2
        Invoke([&capturedVal1, &capturedVal2]{std::cout << "Values 1, 2: " << capturedVal1 << ", " << capturedVal2 << std::endl;}),
        SetArgPointee<2>(&someOtherMock),
        Return(S_OK)));

You instruct mockObject by SaveArg<0>(&capturedVal1) SaveArg<1>(&capturedVal2) to store data in local variables capturedVal1 and capturedVal2 which lifetime ends at the time when mocked method is invoked.
Move capturedVal1 and capturedVal2 to be a class fields.
Final note:
I no longer use SaveArg<0> and couple other gtest APIs. They are extremely useful when using C++03, but since C++11 it can be replaced by lambda, which is IMHO more handy.
Anyway Why you need those variables at all? You do not use it to anything meaningfull accept printing (which bad). So you can just do this:
  ON_CALL(mockedObject, DoCall(_, _, _))
    .WillByDefault(Invoke([] (auto a, auto b, auto c) {
        std::cout << "Values 1, 2: " << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
        return S_OK;
     })

You should not print anything to std::cout. This makes test very annoying, noisy and there other ways to print values in gtest, so those things are printed only when test fails.

I've tried this already or having them static. It then says: Class field cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration.

Why you made this static? Why you need this capture at all if you can't use this values later?

Using static variables was just a way to try to make sure the captured values would "survive".
In the productive code, the object returned by DoCall depends on the first two parameters. Each object answers differently in DoOtherCall. I only have one mock instance of someOtherMock and wanted derive the correct behaviour in the EXPECT_CALL from the first two parameters to DoCall.

See last update.

Because the code is very minimalistic, the reason for why things are as they are is not visible. So the question for why doesn't help here.
Nevertheless, your input to go for lambda directly to catch the arguments to DoCall is the key for the solution: add class members and assign the parameters to those.
ON_CALL(mockedObject, DoCall(_, _, _))
.WillByDefault(Invoke([this] (auto a, auto b, auto c) {
m_Val1 = a;
m_Val2 = b;
return S_OK;
})

Class members cannot be passed as lambda captures (by ref), but capturing this works. Thanks for your help!
